# Which calculation for the eigenfunction and eigenvalue is wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $\Omega = (0,1)$ and the eigenvalue problem $$-u''(x)+u(x) = \lambda u(x), \quad u'(0)=u(1)=0$$ or equivalently $-u''(x)=(\lambda -1)u(x).$

I first derived $u(x)=\cos(k\pi x)+1$ and $\lambda =k^2\pi^2+1$ which in my opinion solves the problem.

However, a friend of mine calculated $u(x)=\cos(\sqrt{\lambda-1}x )$ and $\lambda=(k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})^2+1$ which also seems to work.

Did one of us miscalculate? Is the eigenfunction 'allowed' to contain the eigenvalue itself as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should use the most general solution of the ODE, let $\mu=\sqrt{\lambda-1}$, then
the most general solution is
$$u(x)=A \sin \mu x+ B \cos \mu x \implies u'(x)=\mu A \cos \mu x - \mu B \sin \mu x$$
$u'(0)=0 \implies A=0$, so the compatible solution is 
$$u(x)=B \cos \mu x, u(1)=0 \implies \cos \mu =0 \implies \mu=(n+1/2)\pi$$ $$\implies \lambda=(n+1/2)^2\pi^2+1, n=0,1,2..$$

Comment: Why is $u(x) = \cos(k\pi x)$ and $\lambda = k^2\pi^2+1$ not possible?

Comment: @Tesla : Because then $u(1)=(-1)^k\ne 0$, the second boundary condition is not satisfied.